# golangで標準出力の最後が改行されているかを検出する

Tags: go

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Print("A")
    line()
    fmt.Println("B")
    line()
    fmt.Println("C")
}

func line() {
   // ?
}
```

このコードで以下のように出力したいです。

```
A
B
C
```

標準出力の最後が改行されているかを検出する方法を教えてください。

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Println によると `Println` は改行を出力するということなので、検出するまでもなく `fmt.Println("C")` は改行を出力します（小泉構文）本当にチェックしたいのは別のことなのでは？

Comment: 直前に`fmt.Print()`を使っていても新しい行に出力したいということです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.Stdout` をラッパー（出力したデータを記憶できるもの）に置き換えればよさそうですが、これは意外と難しいことかも知れません。

`os.Stdout` の型は [`os.File`](https://pkg.go.dev/os#File) です。これが [`io.Writer`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Writer) のようなインターフェースであれば柔軟に扱えたかも知れません。しかし、ファイルとなると、間に処理を挟むラッパーを自作する方法はあまり無さそうです。

下に [`os.Pipe`](https://pkg.go.dev/os#Pipe) を使う方法を考えてみました。これは 0（ヌル文字） を番兵値として使用しているので、0 を出力できません。番兵値など使わずに、単純に最後に出力したデータ（`lastByte`）を公開すればよさそうですが、それをスレッドセーフ（ゴルーチンセーフ）に行なう方法を、私は思い付きませんでした。

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

type lineInserter struct {
    File     *os.File
    OrigFile *os.File
    r        *os.File
    end      chan int
}

func newLineInserter(origFile *os.File) *lineInserter {
    r, w, _ := os.Pipe()
    end := make(chan int)

    go func() {
        buf := make([]byte, 1)
        var lastByte byte = '\n'

        for {
            n, err := r.Read(buf)
            if n == 0 || err != nil {
                break
            }

            if buf[0] == 0 {
                if lastByte != '\n' {
                    origFile.Write([]byte{'\n'})
                    lastByte = buf[0]
                }
            } else {
                origFile.Write(buf)
                lastByte = buf[0]
            }

        }
        close(end)
    }()

    return &lineInserter{
        File:     w,
        OrigFile: origFile,
        r:        r,
        end:      end,
    }
}

func (li *lineInserter) Close() {
    li.File.Close()
    <-li.end
    li.r.Close()
}

func (li *lineInserter) Line() {
    li.File.Write([]byte{0})
}

func main() {
    li := newLineInserter(os.Stdout)
    os.Stdout = li.File
    defer func() {
        os.Stdout = li.OrigFile
        li.Close()
    }()

    li.Line()
    fmt.Print("A")
    li.Line()
    fmt.Println("B")
    li.Line()
    li.Line()
    fmt.Println("C")
    li.Line()
}
```

出力:

```
A
B
C
```

Answer (score 4):

文言「最後に」を、オイラ含むたいていのプログラマは「プログラムの最後」と読みます。が、この質問の場合は文言「直前に」としたほうが良さそうです。

この辺は考え方というか方針というかの問題です。オイラなら「直前に改行が出力されたか」をチェックするのは困難っつか性能的に無駄な処理であると考えて

案１： `fmt.Print("A")` という記述をしていることがそもそも誤りなので、これを `fmt.Println("A")` に修正することを考えます。 `grep` するだけですから技術的に困難はないでしょう。

案２：直接 `fmt.Print` を使うから改行出力が漏れるのです。なのでログ出力（だと思うのですが）用には専用の構造体なり関数なりを自作して、そっちを使うようにします。当然、ログ出力用関数は行末には必ず改行を出力すればよいです。

案３：ログ出力関数は最初に改行を出力するという手もあります。そうするとプログラム終了直前のログには改行コードがつかないことになります。正常終了時には追加で改行のみのログを出力する（異常終了時にはこれをしない）ようにしておくと、ログの最後に改行があるかないかで終了状況が判別できたりします。